# How to display the sum of the cubes of the digits?

Tags: java

**Code:**

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class Cubesum {
public static void main(String args[]){
    int input=0;
    int num1,num2,num3;

    //read the number
    System.out.println("Enter a Number");
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    input= Integer.parseInt(console.nextLine());

    // now let us print the cube of digits
    //i.e if number is 123 we will print 1^3, 2^3 and 3^3
    //we will also add 1 and 3 to output the sum of first
    //and last digits
    int number = input; //number is a temp variable
    int counter = 0; //counter is used to count no of digits

    while(number>0){
        int t= number%10;
        System.out.println("Cube of "+t +" is "+(t*t*t));
        counter = counter+1;
        number = number/10;

    }


}
}
```

**Output:**

```
Enter a Number
**223**
Cube of 3 is 27
Cube of 2 is 8
Cube of 2 is 8
```

How do I add the cubes of these numbers? *For example, 27+8+8 would be 43*

Comment: how did you count the number of digits?

Comment: Store the cube of the number (variable t) into a variable and sum it in each loop.

Comment: Homework, always homework...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you want to do something like this:

```
int number = input;
int sum = 0;
while (number > 0) {
    int digit = number % 10;
    sum += digit * digit * digit;
    number /= 10;
}
```

Comment: /*Java Program to find square, square root and cube of a given number*/
public class j5 
{
 public static void main(String args[]){
  Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
  int num;

  System.out.print("Enter an integer number: ");
  num=sc.nextInt();

  System.out.println("Square of "+ num + " is: "+ Math.pow(num, 2));
  System.out.println("Cube of "+ num + " is: "+ Math.pow(num, 3));
  System.out.println("Square Root of "+ num + " is: "+ Math.sqrt(num));
 }
}

Answer (score 2):

Try this code.

```
int sum=0;
while(number>0){
    int t= number%10;
    System.out.println("Cube of "+t +" is "+(t*t*t));
    sum=sum+(t*t*t);
    counter = counter+1;
    number = number/10;

}
System.out.println(sum);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here a solution:

```
int sum = 0;
while(number>0){
  int t= number%10;
  System.out.println("Cube of "+t +" is "+(t*t*t));
  sum += t*t*t;
  counter = counter+1;
  number = number/10;
}
System.out.println(sum);
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem new to Java, so here is a more simple (and readable) example for you:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class Cubesum {
public static void main(String args[]){

    int num1,num2,num3;
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

    //read the numbers
    System.out.println("Enter the first number");
    num1 = Integer.parseInt(console.nextLine());
    System.out.println("Enter the second number");
    num2 = Integer.parseInt(console.nextLine());
    System.out.println("Enter the third number");
    num3 = Integer.parseInt(console.nextLine());

    int output = (int1*int1*int1)+(int2*int2*int2)+(int3*int3*int3)
    System.out.println("result is:  " + output);


}
}
```

You want to get each number individually then create the result.

Sample input:

```
2

2

3
```

Output should be:

```
43
```